# Summing a single cell Across Several Worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I can easily sum a given cell, say **B9**, across multiple worksheets with something like:

```
=SUM(Sheet7:Sheet11!B9)
```

This is the equivalent to :

```
=Sheet7!B9+Sheet8!B9+Sheet9!B9+Sheet10!B9+Sheet11!B9
```

Which is the sum of cell **B9** in all the worksheets from *Sheet7* through *Sheet11*.
I need to create something like the first formula, but with the sheet names in cells.  So if **A1** contains:

*Sheet7*

and cell **A2** contains:

*Sheet11*

[image]

Then the formula in **A3** would use these cells.  What I have tried so far is:

```
=SUM(A1 & ":" & A2 & "!" & B9)
```

and

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(A1 & ":" & A2 & "!" & B9))
```

Neither of these work.

I can easily create a VBA function to do this, but the workbook must be able to operate in a macro-free environment.

Comment: try this `=SUM(INDIRECT(A1 & ":" & A2 & "!" & "B9"))`

Comment: @KingOfAllTrades  Sadly, I get **#REF!**

Comment: I don't think INDIRECT works well with multiple sheets.  I can get all kinds of ranges to work with INDIRECT on a single sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Dave’s answer and your comment `But I don't know in advance what the contents of cells A1 and A2 will be.......so I don't know how many terms to include.` I would suggest to add a column to include the total of each sheet and sum that column. Say you enter the sheet names in column `A`, then enter in column `B`:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT(A2&"!B9")),INDIRECT(A2&"!B9"),0)
```

Than you can do `=Sum(B:B)` to get the total.

Note that I added the `IF` and `ISNUMBER` function to avoid the `#REF!` when column A is missing a sheet name. You may want to use `ISBLANK` instead, as

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),0,INDIRECT(A2&"!B9"))
```

If you do want to get an error message when column A has a wrong sheet name.

Another tip: If you name your sheets as Sheet1, Sheet2, you can easily drag to fill your sheets in column A

Answer (score 1):

This is a manual approach which may not be ideal

```
=INDIRECT(A1&"!A1")+INDIRECT(A2&"!A1")
```

or

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(A1&"!A1"),INDIRECT(A2&"!A1"))
```

My worksheet looked like

```
     A         B         C
1    sheet2
2    sheet3
3
```

And in Sheet2 A1 had a value as does Sheet3 A1

In your case, you would need

```
   =SUM(INDIRECT(A1&"!A1"),INDIRECT(A2&"!A1"),INDIRECT(A3&"!A1"),INDIRECT(A4&"!A1")...etc)
```

Comment: Thank you for this response.  I tried the second formula and it correctly summed the values for **Sheet7** and **Sheet11**, but none of the sheets in between.

Comment: no sadly, you will need to enter each sheet as a new cell value in your worksheet1...

Comment: But I don't know in advance what the contents of cells **A1** and **A2** will be.......so I don't know how many terms to include.

Comment: You may want to update your question with that :(

Comment: I have added the sentence which, hopefully clarifies my request......... ** once again thank you for your help. **